# Fix hovered element's position within centered text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have centered elements within container, and I want to give hovered element left padding while keep its position.
Could it be possible?

Look, here's an example:

```css
    body {
      font-size: 2em;
    }
    .container {
        text-align: center;
    }

    .item:hover {
      padding-left: 0.5em;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="container">
        <span class="item">Hello</span>
        <span class="item">my</span>
        <span class="item">wonderful</span>
        <span class="item">world</span>
    </div>
```

When you hover element you'll notice it change its position across x-axis, but it need to be fixed pushing other elements instead.

Comment: Just use this instead: `padding: 0 0.5em;`

Comment: What do you mean by "it need to be fixed pushing other elements instead"? You want the elements to the right be moved as well, or everything should stay?

Comment: @RoboRobok, Left padding affects only elements to the left, so elements to the right should be where they are.

Comment: @ChrisG, the tricky part of the question is that I don't need both paddings, only left.

Comment: my answer didn't work for you? I am keeping the hover element fixed and moving all the others. It's also a generic solution if you want to also have a right movement

Comment: @TemaniAfif, Yes, It looks over-tricky, but it works. Thanks for the idea of container's hover style.

Comment: Can you clarify why you don't want to add padding on the right, given what a simple way it is to solve this issue? Why does it matter where the padding is added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like below to have both spaces

```css
body {
  font-size: 2em;
}

.container {
  text-align: center;
  pointer-events:none;
}
.item {
  position:relative;
  left:0;
  transition:0.5s;
  pointer-events:initial;
}

/* previous elements: move to left */
.container:hover .item{
  left:-10px;
}
/* hovered element: don't move  */
.container .item:hover {
  left:0; 
}
/* next elements: move to right 
*/
.container .item:hover ~ *{
  left:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="item">Hello</span>
  <span class="item">my</span>
  <span class="item">wonderful</span>
  <span class="item">world</span>
</div>
```

And with only left space:

```css
body {
  font-size: 2em;
}

.container {
  text-align: center;
  pointer-events:none;
}
.item {
  position:relative;
  left:0;
  transition:0.5s;
  pointer-events:initial;
}

.container:hover .item{
  left:-10px;
}

.container .item:hover,
.container .item:hover ~ *{
  left:0; 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="item">Hello</span>
  <span class="item">my</span>
  <span class="item">wonderful</span>
  <span class="item">world</span>
</div>
```

Or only right space:

```css
body {
  font-size: 2em;
}

.container {
  text-align: center;
  pointer-events:none;
}
.item {
  position:relative;
  left:0;
  transition:0.5s;
  pointer-events:initial;
}

.container .item:hover ~ *{
  left:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="item">Hello</span>
  <span class="item">my</span>
  <span class="item">wonderful</span>
  <span class="item">world</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I've understood you correctly but try the below out and see if that produces the effect you are looking for:

### Solution

```
body {
  font-size: 2em;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.item {
  padding: 0 .2rem;
  transition: padding .2s;
}

.item:hover {
  padding: 0 .5em;
}
```

### Explanation

By leveraging flexbox we can make all the "spans" a flex item, and align them centrally with justify content (using the "center" value) on the parent. The one issue with doing this is that we lose the natural space to the left and right of each text item so I added a small amount of padding to the item class.

Once hovered over, I have successfully increased the padding to the left and right.

Because we are setting everything to align center and increasing the left and right padding, the other text is pushed away from it like a repel effect.
Again I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for but I hope it is near and helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the main point here that I need only left padding on hovered element, you got both left and right. Check it here, hovered element still moves, https://codepen.io/interlark/pen/qBNBWKZ